# UVM sequence body task gives unknown compilation error

Tags: syntax-error, verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I have the following code block where a syntax error is fired:

```
 virtual task body();
     forever begin
    my_transaction m_req;
    // Blocking wait for a transaction request:
    p_sequencer.m_request_fifo.get(m_req);
    // Generate response based on "req_kind" value:
    if ( m_req.req_kind == REQ ) begin
       `uvm_do_with(req, {req_kind == REQ;} )
    end
    else begin
       `uvm_do_with(req, {req_kind == NO_REQ;} )       
    end
     end
  endtask
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error-[SE] Syntax error
  Following verilog source has syntax error :
  "./src/my_transaction.sv", 77: token is ')'
    if ( m_req.req_kind == REQ ) begin
                                      ^
```

If I comment the if and else lines as follows, this code block compiles normally:

```
  virtual task body();
     forever begin
    my_transaction m_req;
    // Blocking wait for a transaction request:
    p_sequencer.m_request_fifo.get(m_req);
    // Generate response based on "req_kind" value:
    //if ( m_req.req_kind == REQ ) begin
       `uvm_do_with(req, {req_kind == REQ;} )
    //end
    //else begin
       `uvm_do_with(req, {req_kind == NO_REQ;} )       
    //end
     end
  endtask
```

I tried commenting this line:

```
my_transaction m_req;
```

as well and expected an error to fire up due to undefined `m_req` identifier. But the code actually compiles!

The definition of req_kind is:

```
class my_transaction extends uvm_sequence_item;
   typedef enum {REQ, NO_REQ} req_kind_e;
   rand req_kind_e req_kind;
...
...
...
```

and the class `my_transaction`  is type forwarded in the file where the compilation error is present:

```
typedef class my_transaction ;
```

The code block in question is a sequence in a sequence library where `m_request_fifo` is the port used in the slave sequencer to retrieve the sequence.

I'm compiling this file along with other files. Is the compiler error message misleading? What other places in code i can look for to know the source of the problem?

What can possibly be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for the declaration of the `uvm_sequence` class is:

```
virtual class uvm_sequence #(
    type    REQ  =  uvm_sequence_item,
    type    RSP  =  REQ
) extends uvm_sequence_base
```

`REQ` is a *type parameter*. Your using it for something else is wrong/confusing your compiler.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used `REQ` and didn't know it's definition is already reserved by UVM. I changed it to `REQUEST` and `NO_REQUEST` and it compiles now.